# Add hashmap in to hashmap as avalue

Tags: java, hashmap

In the below code, am creating a temp hashmap and adding it as value to another hashmap, at the end of the while loop the csvList hashmap has only the last value of the temp has map that was added as a value, all other values are null

The key is retained and all values are replaced by null.
What am i doing wrong here, is it the temp.clear or where the temp hashmap is declared.

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> csvList = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
List<String> line = null;
try {
    inputStream = new FileInputStream(csvFile);

    //scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
    scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    //scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");

    int i = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        //tempMap.clear();
        if (i == 0) {
            headList = parseLine(scanner.nextLine());
            i++;
        } else {
            line = parseLine(scanner.nextLine());
            pKey = "";

            for (int j = 0; j < line.size(); j++) {
                if (!selectClause.toLowerCase().contains(headList.get(j).toLowerCase()))
                    continue;
                else {
                    // Change for multiple PKeys
                    if (primaryKey.toLowerCase().contains(headList.get(j).toLowerCase())) {
                        pKey = pKey + line.get(j);
                    }
                    if (headList.get(j).equalsIgnoreCase(primaryKey))
                        pKey = line.get(j);
                    tempMap.put(headList.get(j).toLowerCase(), line.get(j));
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(i++);
            line.clear();
            csvList.put(pKey, tempMap);
        }
        //tempMap.clear();

    }
    headList.clear();
    //tempMap.clear();
    scanner.close();
    }

    return csvList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create the tempMap outside the while loop so it is the same instance you use all the time, move the creation inside the loop so each pKey in the csvList gets a unique instance

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ...
```